# Best workflow for developing and debugging - initially deploy in a docker environment

Tags: docker, go

Programming Go in a Docker container or not?

For some time now, I have looked for a good way to program, debug and finally deploy to Docker environment.

1. I have looked at VS Code, debugging into a container via Delve. It is difficult to attach to the debugger.
2. Using Eclipse Che, not supported in the IDE.

Since Docker is written in Go - the good people at Docker - they must have a good workflow?

Maybe the conslusion is, that I should not develope and debug inside a container but from host machine - and then only deploy when compiled into a container.

What is you experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using docker to deliver our products nowadays, and just like you said, we develop and debug them from the host machine. And if we meet some issue which is hard to repo with the runtime enviroment staff, we attach the debug binary to the docker image to replace the built in ones.